# Does Apache Spark load entire data from target database?

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, vertica, apache-spark-sql

I want to use Apache Spark and connect to Vertica by JDBC.

In Vertica database, I have 100 million records and spark code runs on another server.

When I run the query in Spark and monitor network usage, traffic between two servers is very high.

It seems Spark loads all data from target server.

this is my code:

```
test_df = spark.read.format("jdbc")
    .option("url" , url).option("dbtable", "my_table")
    .option("user", "user").option("password" , "pass").load()

test_df.createOrReplaceTempView('tb')

data = spark.sql("select * from tb")

data.show()
```

when I run this, after 2 minutes and very high network usage, result returned.

Does Spark load the entire data from target database?

Comment: You can use `sql("select count(*) from spark_table").explain(true)` to see the query plan, that might give you more insights.

Answer (score 0):

`JDBC` based `DBs` allow push down queries so that you will read from the disk only relevant items: ex: `df.filter("user_id == 2").count` will first select only records filtered and then ship count to spark. So using `JDBC`: 1. plan for filters, 2. partition your DB according to your query patterns and further optimise form spark side as ex:

```
val prop = new java.util.Properties
prop.setProperty("driver","org.postgresql.Driver")
prop.setProperty("partitionColumn", "user_id")
prop.setProperty("lowerBound", "1")
prop.setProperty("upperBound", "272")
prop.setProperty("numPartitions", "30")
```

However, most `relational DB` are partitioned by specific fields in a tree lke structure which is not ideal for complex big data queries: I strongly suggest to copy the table from `JDBC` to `no-sql` such as `cassandra`, `mongo`, `elastic serach` or file systems such as `alluxio` or `hdfs` in order to enable scalable - parallel - complex - fast queries. Lastly, you can replace `JDBC` with `aws redshift` which should not be that hard to implement for backend / front end, however from your spark side it is a pain to deal with re dependency conflicts - but it will enable you to conduct complex queries much faster as it partition columns so you can have push down aggregates on columns themselves using multiple workers
.

Comment: for this command in spark: 

result = df.filter(df.test_col == 1).count(), 

 Spark run this query on database: 

SELECT 1 FROM Event WHERE ("test_col" IS NOT NULL) AND ("test_col" = 1) . 

"select 1" cause very high network traffic for big results. how can I get count in different way ?

Answer (score 0):

After your spark jobs finishes logon to the Vertica database using the same credentials that the spark job used and run:

```
SELECT * FROM v_monitor.query_requests ORDER BY start_timetamp DESC LIMIT 10000;
```

This will show you the queries sent to the database by the spark job, allowing you to see if it pushed down the count(*) to the database or if it indeed tried to retrieve the entire table across the network.